# Why is my question about auto-configuring an enterprise router off topic?

Tags: discussion, support

I have a question about my Network Engineering Stack Exchange post: [dnsmasq not responding to Cisco tftp broadcast requests (tftp://255.255.255.255/network-confg)](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49909/dnsmasq-not-responding-to-cisco-tftp-broadcast-requests-tftp-255-255-255-255)

I'm trying to query the knowledge of network engineers over at networkengineering about engineering a network (setting up a router auto-config). The question is marked as off topic apparently because it involves a server somehow. I don't agree with Ron Maupin's reasoning that this falls outside the purview of network engineering.

Answer (score 2):

> the server does not respond to the request on the broadcast IP

That means it's not a router configuration issue. Furthermore, he's provided zero information on how the router and server are connected / supposed to see each other. If the server isn't seeing broadcasts from the router, that's an issue with either the server or the network. We have insufficient information to determine which or offer a solution.

> Has anyone experienced issues configuring Cisco routers via their default config directive

No, I haven't. But *"I know what I'm doing"*. I know how my network is setup. I know how my server is setup. I know how my software is configured. And I know how to troubleshoot all of the parts -- and I'm perfectly happy helping others to do the same. The original question has no information to assist in even *guessing* what might be wrong.

(I've been to this rodeo. Helping a friend setup a system to reset Cisco phones. A week of back-and-forth by email ends with me driving out to his office to find the problem was something I had twice asked and "confirmed" wasn't the problem -- laptop has multiple network interfaces and the software is listening on the wrong one! I.e. not. a. network. engineering. problem.)

Answer (score -1):

I agree with @TobiV. This does not seem off topic.

The OP is not asking about the specific configuration steps for their TFTP software on the server. The OP is asking for guidance on what is required by Cisco Routers for the Auto Configuration via TFTP feature.

Very clearly a Network Engineering question. I have voted to re-open.

(but regrettably, very few posts on this forum get re-opened due to member vote, so you're best bet is to appeal to the mods for an insta-re-open).

Comment: There is no configuration to be done on the router. It is a completely unconfigured router, and the point is that it configures itself from properly configured DHCP and FTP/TFTP servers. The servers are not responding to the requests from the router, so, it is either a server problem, or it is a problem on the network, but there is no network information necessary to troubleshoot the network.

Comment: @RonMaupin `it configures itself from properly configured DHCP and FTP/TFTP servers` -- the details of how this works would be appropriate answers for this forum. What file does it query? What does it make the query to? What IP does it send the queries from? How often does it query? What confreg settings are required for this feature? What other considerations are involved in the auto-tftp-configuration feature?

Comment: The point is that there is nothing that needs to be done on the router itself; it is a completely unconfigured router. The magic all takes place on the server, and he is asking how to get that up to layer-7 on the server. That is off-topic here. The other possibility is that there is a network problem, and I repeatedly asked for that, and pointed to the Network Engineering Question Checklist. There simply isn't enough information in the question to even start with that, and he will not provide it.

Comment: I did point out that the router needs to get an address from a DHCP server with option 43, but he basically didn't discuss that. We cannot help him with the DHCP server configuration, nor the FTP/TFTP server configuration. FTP and TFTP need an IP address, and that first must come from the DHCP server, but he isn't getting that. It is either an off-topic server problem, or it is a network problem where we have no information to help with that. All he needs to do is provide the requested information because speculation and guessing is off-topic.